# C++ compile time checking of type equality in a preprocessor directive

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, type-traits

I'd like to check if two POD types are equal at compile time in C++11.  I'm trying to #define function names that are appropriate for the Float_T type.  Here is what I tried:

```
#include <type_traits>

using Float_T = double;
// using Float_T = float;

#if is_same<Float_T, double>::value
    #define LOG2  log2
#else
    #define LOG2  log2f
#endif

 g++ complains:  error: extra text after expected end of preprocessing directive
  #if is_same<Float_T, double>::value
                     ^
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: do you mean c++11?

Comment: C or C++? Compile-time constants are used at compile, not parse time.

Comment: BTW, if you use [`std::log2`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2), functions are already overloaded so the trick is useless.

Comment: You can not use an STL feature (is_same) as a condition for pre-processor macro. C preprocessor knows nothing about STL and can not evaluate it. Beside, the whole snippet looks like exercise in futility and smells XY problem.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do something like this.  What is your actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I need to compile different code blocks based on whether the Float_T type is equal to float or double.    Can you suggest one or more methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are evaluated when the [source code is being parsed, much before compilation kicks in](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor), which is why it is nothing more than a simple copy-paste mechanism. So, doing something like this:

```cpp
#if is_same<Float_T, double>::value
    #define LOG2  log2
#else
    #define LOG2  log2f
#endif
```

Is practically impossible since `is_same` and `#if` are evaluated at different times during the whole compilation procedure. What you *can* do is to change the macro into a function, like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cmath>

using Float_T = double;

template <typename T = Float_T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, double>::value, double>::type LOG2(Float_T const& x) {
    return log2(x);
}

template <typename T = Float_T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, double>::value, float>::type LOG2(Float_T const& x) {
    return log2f(x);
}

// ...
```

Comment: Should be `LOG2(Float_T const& x)`, else `T` is deduced from parameter and Float_T  is unused.

Comment: These functions can never be evaluated as a constant expression since neither `log` nor `logf` are defined to be `constexpr`. The `constexpr` here is meaningless. If I'm not mistaken, a function marked `constexpr` that can never be evaluated as a constant expression makes the program ill-formed, with no diagnostic required.

Comment: @Ruks thanks for a gentle response to a silly attempt to use the preprocessor.  I guess that if I want to use the preprocessor to compile or not compile certain code blocks based on the actual type of Float_T, my only option is to define Float_T as a macro (#define), not an alias or typedef.   Is that right?